# Goerli Eth not showing up on metamask

Tags: metamask, wallets, etherscan, faucets, goerli

I have tried 3 ways to get goerli eth -

1. the alchemy faucet. [The alchemy Goerli faucet](https://goerlifaucet.com/?a=829a4dd348). The transaction link on etherscan:
   https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x9ddbe5d5d796d3838a2475db39b337fabfc651a2800d0e33284d22dc0fe92d99
2. A PoW faucet. (https://goerli-faucet.pk910.de/).  The transaction link on etherscan:
   https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xf85d60f55cc218c9b007f890b3ae8930113e6955c5ca52799f5ffcacdd6bc860
3. [Via twitter or facebook] https://goerli-faucet.mudit.blog/ . This is giving **Insufficient gas+price x value**

Even though I see the top 2 transactions went through, no goerli eth is showing up on my metamask wallet. If possible, could someones seeing this **directly send me goerli eth**? Or **another faucet that will work**?

Answer (score 1):

For the Alchemy faucet, you can get it directly here: https://goerlifaucet.com/. Also if you need more, you can go there and get more daily

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's weird cause I can see some balance on your account
I suggest you try another testnet if you don't need it to be on goerli

Comment: I'm following the freecodecamp tutorial by patrick collins. The chainlink data feeds have other testnets like Rinkeby and Kovan deprecated. I do have Eth on those two networks and everything is working fine there. I'd prefer to use either of those two but I am stuck with Goerli.

Comment: Maybe stick to the hardhat node until the test networks addresses are updated...
I've personally never used Goerli before, so I cannot help with that

Answer (score 0):

At Metamask Add new network/specials/Show test networks and you will see your balance.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use Alchemy's free [Goerli faucet](https://goerlifaucet.com/?a=18798bffa0).

However, we'd recommend using Sepolia as your Ethereum testnet instead of Goerli. Given the Goerli shortage, Sepolia is most reliable.

Feel free to use Alchemy's free [Sepolia Faucet](https://sepoliafaucet.com/?a=18798bffa0).